# How can I install hyper v without formatting my c drive

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-8, formatting, hyper-v

I want to install hyper v so I can get virtual machines of XP for internet explorer testing purposes. However the installation says that it will format my drive, but I don't want to lose any of my files. How can I install it without losing any data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows 8, you can enable Hyper V by opening "Programs and Features" under Settings (do a search). From there, you should be able to enable Hyper V without re-installing.

[image: enable-hv-win-8]